# Map Marker Code Not Working in Bootstrap Template

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im building a site for a friend of mine and im having a hell of time trying to get the map marker to show up, I gotta admit im not much for java coding but Ive done my share of it. Im a designer and 3d motion graphics artist.

Im currently working on this template in Dreamweaver CC and I chose it cause thats how Ive been constructing sites for years.

So he gave me a template that he wanted me to use 427_timeline (its A freebie).

The modified version of this template can be seen here [http://johnnybobs3ddesignz.com/](http://johnnybobs3ddesignz.com/coming_soon/)

My first time but works the same pretty much. Heres My code, if someone could help me Id appreciate that so much, it would be mighty groovy dude ;)

```
<script>
function initialize()
{
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.073809, -118.323371),
    zoom: 15,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("templatemo-map")
    ,mapOptions);

  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(34.073809, -118.323371);

  var contentString = '<h2>Runyon Investment & Realty</p>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString 
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mylatLng,
    title: 'Runyon Investment & Realty',
    visible: true
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() 
{
  map.setCenter(center);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use this link

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/
```

to get desired informations.

for example use the following snippet.
They use the

```
map - option
```

in the init of the marker. Just try that in your code too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple markers</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Already been there, nothing is working, Ive tried every post I could find here too to rectify the problem but no joy bro ;)

Comment: Just use one of the examples as starting point to see how its done correctly. I edited my answer to show the simplest using of markers.

Comment: when I add the line->     center: myLatlng } it breaks it

Comment: You mean where you have to add it? Just inside your map options. Be sure to do the initialization of myLatLIng before passing it to map options: So place var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922); before var mapOptions = ... .

Comment: Okay you are correct bro, I copied this and put my cordinates in and it worked. Thank You very much for your help I appreciate it very much dude ;)

Comment: No problem bro! Maybe you want to mark my answer as correct? :D

Comment: Your awesome man, thank ya, thank ya very much. I am trying to understand what i did wrong, is it this line var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.073809, -118.323371),

Comment: I marked it but it wont let me upvote yet, ill come back and do that later

Answer (score 0):

I get two javascript errors with your code as is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mylatLng is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined
```

Because `mylatLng` is not defined in your code (you define `location`) and `map` is local to your `initialize` function

Working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.073809, -118.323371),
    zoom: 15,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("templatemo-map"), mapOptions);

  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(34.073809, -118.323371);

  var contentString = '<h2>Runyon Investment & Realty</p>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    title: 'Runyon Investment & Realty',
    visible: true
  });
  marker.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
    map.setCenter(center);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#templatemo-map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="templatemo-map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: Ah! I see said the blind man... Thank you for pointing that out to me dude. This place is awesome man. Im gonna learn a lot here I suspect